# 'The requested resource was not found on this server' error in IIS

Tags: permissions, php, iis, .net-framework, windows-server-2022

I have configured IIS (ver 10) in Server 2022 edition and added few sites which including php,Dot net technologies etc. The sites were working fine except some DB issues which i was working on it. Today when i checked the sites some of them are not loading and throwing this error "The requested resource was not found on this server." I dont understand because these sites are working fine and i didnt do any changes.

[image: This is what am getting]

Things i have tried.

> Restart the IIS server,W3SVC service, Server itself.
> Checking all the directories and bindings.
> Adding permission to IIS and IIS_IUSRS users.
> Creating a test website and an index.html file in it, that also throws the same error.
> Checking logs in inetpub directory and system32 directory (no matching data with time found) also in the Event viewer.

The weird thing is some sites are working which is in the same folder structure and same permissions.

Can anybody please help me on this since i have no clue why this error is poping up, i am left with no option other than setting a new server.I think the IIS configuration is the issue here and i need to know a way to check where are the settings also is there a way to repair/restore the IIS service files.

Comment: Which resource is not found? Have you verified that it exists?

Comment: so we can't help you without some real specifics like the failing urls, the structure of your site and apps, etc. I would double check your default document settings if you are not using a url that specifies a file/page. confirm your app pools are running, and try browsing the site from the server itself, to see any detailed error messages.

Comment: @harrymc which resource is not found, i am also not sure. The files and bindings all are in place.

Comment: @FrankThomas the site is actually a php based site, also i have hosted a dotnet based site. for php and dotnet i have configured the usual things like handler mappings,dotnet core versions etc. Also i dont think its site technology specific because even i have tried a normal test site with index.html content only that also throwing the same issue.Yes the app pools are running i have confirmed. I am browsing the site from server itself, but other than inetpub folder,system32 logs and event viewer logs i dont know where else to look.

Comment: I am having strong doubt that somehow the iis configuration is corrupted because all of this sites were working fine. But i dont know how to repair or where to look for IIS configuration files.

Comment: Without locating the missing resource, we can't help. Check all resources used by the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled IIS feature and everythings works fine now. Still the the root cause of issue is a mystery.